# Save XElement to Root in UWP with FolderPicker

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2015, uwp, filestream

I've come to a strange error I cannot understand...

I've been using the FolderPicker in a UWP app to allow a user to choose a folder, and I need to allow an xml file to be saved to the directory chosen.  In many cases, this would be the root folder of a thumb drive.

The current code I have works fine when I choose a subfolder of the drive ("G:\Newfolder"), but fails when I choose the root ("G:\")

The error that I get claims that I do not have proper access, but I get the same error when I had accidentally escaped the slashes incorrectly, so I'm not trustful of the error code.

Is it impossible for me to save to the root of a thumb drive?  Is there another mistake I'm making?

Here is the code:

```
private async void buttonSaveToRoot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml");



        //OK, imagine me picking the root of my thumb drive - "G:\"
        StorageFolder pickedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        if (pickedFolder != null)
        {
            Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", pickedFolder);
            XElement xml = new XElement("Food");
            xml.Add (new XElement("Oranges", new XAttribute("Type", "Fruit")));
            xml.Add(new XElement("Apples", new XAttribute("Type", "Fruit")));
            xml.Add(new XElement("Potatoes", new XAttribute("Type", "Vegetables")));
            xml.Add(new XElement("Carrots", new XAttribute("Type", "Vegetables")));

            string savePath = pickedFolder.Path + @"\test.xml";
            savePath = savePath.Replace(@"\\", @"\") ;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.Yield();
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(savePath))
                {
                    xml.Save(fs);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just a general observation:

Whenever you're combining paths, do not manually enter slashes, but instead, use

```
var savePath = Path.Combine(pickedFolder.Path, "test.xml");
```

Saves you a few potential Homer Simpson "doh" moments :)

Comment: Thank you!  Once I have enough reputation my upvote on that will count for something...  I guess I'm still slow on getting into the "Brave New World" and I'm doing some things the old-fashioned way in error.

It worries me though - using that I am now certain that I'm not getting the path wrong, which means there really seems to be some inhibition to writing to the root.  :/